# c# Route config for specific URL only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this URL

```
http://localhost:51095/Person/Walk/10
```

Using RouteConfig how can I remove the controller part without affecting other URL's.

So this will become

`http://localhost:51095/Walk/10`

This is the order also, they are affecting other URL's

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Walk", // Route name
                "{action}/{distance}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Person", action = "Walk" } // Parameter defaults,
            );

routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

But this one also affected other Routes

Comment: Did you considered `Attribute Routing` for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be more specific:

```
routes.MapRoute("Walk",
                "Walk/{distance}",
                new { controller = "Person", action = "Walk" });
```

Comment: is the order in routeconfig affects the result also?

Comment: @Sherlock Yes, you should map the most specific routes first, and then the generic ones. This one should be on top.

Comment: this is affecting other URLs, by the way the controller name and action have the same name

Comment: @Sherlock Such as?

Comment: The problem is, my action name have the same name with my controller name, don't mind the example. So to have another example, I have this URL `localhost:<port>/Person/Person/12` if I take your suggestion it will affect the other URL's because the controller name is the same with my action name :3

Comment: Can you edit the original question to cater for the 'same Action/Controller name' issue that you're having?